# Properly select piece of state from store

Tags: angular, ngrx

I want to subscribe to a piece of state in the ngrx store and receive emissions only when that specific piece of state gets changed.

`export const getMatchesState = (state: State) => state.matches;`

```
export const getSpainMatches = createSelector(getMatchesState, (allMatches) => {
  return Object.keys(allMatches.byId)
    .filter(key => {
      return allMatches.byId[key].tournamentId == '68';
    }).map(key => allMatches.byId[key]);
});
```

when I subscribe to this likeso

```
this.testSub = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getSpainMatches))
      .subscribe(s => console.log('@@@@', s));
```

I get emissions each time any match from store was changed, not only when a spain match has changed.

**Update:**

I also tried this:

```
export const getSpainMatches = createSelector(getMatchesState, (allMatches, props) => {
  return Object.keys(allMatches.byId)
    .filter(key => {
      return allMatches.byId[key].tournamentId == props.tournamentId ;
    }).map(key => allMatches.byId[key]);
});
```

```
this.testSub = this.store.pipe(select(fromRoot.getSpainMatches, {tournamentId: 68}))
      .subscribe(s => console.log('@@@@', s));
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could try using distinctUntilChanged somewhere... maybe in your subscribe.

```
this.testSub = this.store.pipe(distinctUntilChanged(), select(fromRoot.getSpainMatches))
      .subscribe(s => console.log('@@@@', s));
```